# Express router executing first function found rather than reading endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to make a requisition that triggers the Controller.getMap method but instead the server is executing the first get function it finds.

> BACKEND (Node.js & Express.js):

```
    const router = require("express").Router()
    const Controller = require("../controllers/Controller")

    router.get("/:id?", Controller.get)
    router.get("/map", Controller.getMap)
```

> FRONTEND REQUISITION (React.js):

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    async function getData() {
        await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/map")
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data)
                setData(data.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

Comment: You have to put the dynamic route after the static route, like `router.get("/map", Controller.getMap); router.get("/:id?", Controller.get);`.

Comment: Ohhh now I see that "map" would be recognized as an id. Thanks!